# Truncate a VARCHAR to specific length in Derby AUTOMATICALLY

Tags: java, string, varchar, derby, javadb

How can I truncate a VARCHAR to the table field length AUTOMATICALLY in Derby using SQL?

To be specific:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( B VARCHAR(2) );
INSERT INTO A B VALUES ('1234');
```

would throw a SQLException:

```
A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR '123' to length 2.
```

Is there a easy way to suppress this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You should chop it off after checking the meta-data. Or if you don't wanna check the meta-data everytime, then you must keep both your code and database in sync. But thats not a big deal, its a usual practice in validators.

Comment: This table is used everywhere. Keeping the code in sync is not easy.

Comment: In sync with database I mean. Its not a big deal, it wouldn't be every now and then. Ask yourself a question how often you will be modifying the length of the field in your database. These kinda validation goes hand-in-hand with databases contraints, I don't see any issue with this.

Comment: And if you really wanna do that, check for meta-data before insert, it would result in a performance lack, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the varchar before inserting it.
use the trim function in your insert script/procedure.

I'm not familiar with Derby, but in MSSQL I do exactly the same thing, using trim to avoid truncation error (only where I don't need the full data), it's much more preferable to increase the length of the varchar

Comment: Increasing the varchar is no desirable here, I believe. He is having no issues with truncation, truncation is even a preferable behavior for him. Secondly, trim only work for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTR`:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( B VARCHAR(2) );
INSERT INTO A B VALUES (SUBSTR('1234', 1, 2));
```

In case you use prepared statements:

```
INSERT INTO A B VALUES (SUBSTR(?, 1, 2));
```