# VARCHAR does not work as expected in Apache Derby

Tags: java, sql, derby, varchar

I'm having [this same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016901/truncate-a-varchar-to-specific-length-in-derby-automatically):

> How can I truncate a VARCHAR to the
>   table field length AUTOMATICALLY in
>   Derby using SQL?
>
> To be specific:
>
> CREATE TABLE A ( B VARCHAR(2) );
>   INSERT INTO A B VALUES ('1234'); would
>   throw a SQLException:
>
> A truncation error was encountered
>   trying to shrink VARCHAR '123' to
>   length 2.

that is already answered:

> No. You should chop it off after
>   checking the meta-data. Or if you
>   don't wanna check the meta-data
>   everytime, then you must keep both
>   your code and database in sync. But
>   thats not a big deal, its a usual
>   practice in validators.

but my doubt is: isn't VARCHAR suppose to variate its size to fit the data? What's wrong with apache derby's VARCHAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VARCHAR type *is* variable length, but the number you supply in its definition is the **maximum** number of characters you're allowing it to have.

`VARCHAR(2)` will stores values that are 0-2 characters, as opposed to `CHAR(2)` which will store 2 characters regardless of what data it actually has.

Side Note: Once you get to 255 characters, consider using the `TEXT` type instead.

Comment: According to the Derby docs, it doesn't support the TEXT type, but perhaps LONG VARCHAR would make sense.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

No, what you describe has nothing to do with that: varchar will not pad with spaces, char will pad with spaces

so if you have

```
CREATE TABLE A ( B VARCHAR(20) ); INSERT INTO A B VALUES ('1234')
```

it will use 4 bytes not 20 bytes, however you can't fit more than 20 characters into that column, either check before inserting or use something like a LEFT(val,2) function

But then again would you not want to know that your data isn't fitting and being truncated. After all the most important thing is your data...if your data is fault you have nothing

In SQL Server there is a setting you can use and it will do this for you, see [Suppress string or binary data would be truncated messages with the ANSI WARNINGS setting](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/surpress-string-or-binary-data-would-be-)

Basically you need SET ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF but I don't know if that works with your DB